# SearchFeature in ol-ext doesn't provide with dropdown options, errorless

Tags: openlayers, search, ol-ext

I'm trying to use ol-ext `ol.control.SearchFeature()` control to search for layer names but unsuccessful. No errors in the console at all.

The modules I've imported:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/ol-layerswitcher/src/ol-layerswitcher.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.js"></script>
```

The GeoJSON layer:

[image]

ol.layer.Vector:

```
const WorldCapitalsGeoJSON = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
        url: './Data/geoJSON/world_capital_cities.geojson',
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        
    }),
    visible: true,
    title: 'World Capital Cities',
    style: new ol.style.Style({
        fill: fillStyleCapitals,
        stroke: strokeStyleCapitals,
        image: circleStyleCapitals
    })
});
map.addLayer(WorldCapitalsGeoJSON)
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
  var search = new ol.control.SearchFeature({
    source: WorldCountriesGeoJSON, // of type ol.source.Vector
    property: "name"
});
  
map.addControl(search)
```

Comment: There is not enough of code to guess what/where it goes wrong. Please add more relevant code about GeoJSON layers.

Comment: @TomazicM I've updated the inquiry. Hope this helps. Thank you

Comment: Code for creation of `WorldCapitalsGeoJSON` layer is still missing.

Comment: @TomazicM sorry, I've updated that also. And I figured out that I've been keeping my layers visibility as false, when I corrected that I get the following error: "Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined" error occurs when the slice() method is called on an undefined value.

Comment: Try with `ol.layer.Vector` instead of `ol.layer.VectorImage`.

Comment: Any errors in the browser debugger network section?

Comment: @TomazicM no errors in the console now. But the widget doesn't drop down any options when I type in something.

Comment: `source` should be a source, but you have specified a layer.  Try `source: WorldCapitalsGeoJSON.getSource(),`

Comment: Thank you so much Mike ! That worked !

Answer (score 0):

`WorldCapitalsGeoJSON.getSource()` was the solution to my problem.